# (React.js)Why the state is not changed instantly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I've changed the state here by dropping a object inside `players`. but it seems the state is not changed instantly? Is it a feature or a bug I made somewhere else?

```
console.log("Before(length):"+this.state.players.length);
players=players.filter(player => player.id !== id2);}
this.setState({players});
console.log("After(length):"+this.state.players.length);
```

the result is

```
Before(length):6
After(length):6
```

which should be 5 afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
>   update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
>   delay it, and then update several components in a single pass.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: This question has multiple duplicates on SO.